# Vuetify - Gaveta de Navegação com itens de lista aninhados

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2, vuetify

Estou tentando criar uma gaveta de navegação com itens de lista aninhados como este: [Painel de Navegação Vuetify](https://demos.creative-tim.com/vuetify-material-dashboard-pro/#/)

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app clipped>
            <v-list dense>
                <template>
                    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
                        <v-list-group v-if="item.items" v-model="item.active" :prepend-icon="item.action" no-action link>
                            <template v-slot:activator>
                                <v-list-item-content>
                                    <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
                                </v-list-item-content>
                            </template>
                            <v-list-item v-for="subItem in item.items" :key="subItem.title" :to="subItem.to">
                                <v-list-item-icon>
                                    <v-icon v-text="subItem.action"></v-icon>
                                </v-list-item-icon>
                                <v-list-item-content>
                                    <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title"></v-list-item-title>
                                </v-list-item-content>
                            </v-list-item>
                        </v-list-group>
                        <v-list-item v-else :to="item.to" link>
                            <v-list-item-icon>
                                <v-icon v-text="item.action"></v-icon>
                            </v-list-item-icon>
                            <v-list-item-content>
                                <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item-content>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
```

Script

```
items: [
                {
                    action: 'fa-chart-line',
                    title: 'Dashboard',
                    to: '/dashboard'
                },
                {
                    action: 'fa-user',
                    title: 'Attractions',
                    items: [
                        {
                            title: 'Home',
                            action: 'fa-barcode',
                            to: '/home'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {...}
            ]
        }),
```

No entanto, quando clico em um item de lista não aninhado, os outros itens ainda estão com o estado ativo e as classes ativas têm cores diferentes.

[image: Menu]

Não encontrei nenhum exemplo nos documentos do Vuetify com um menu com elementos aninhados e não aninhados, mas encontrei esse modelo que é exatamente o que estou procurando.

Um exemplo que fiz no
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fabiosantos97/pen/abzLzML?editors=1010)

Comment: Você pode deixar as cores dos "subItems" ja definidas com uma classe ou `style` mesmo. Entende-se que para exibi-los o "item pai" obrigatoriamente é ativo. Então deixei uma cor ja definida.

Comment: @RubensBarbosa, desculpe não entendi exatamente sua resposta, eu devo deixar um style com a cor já definida para um subitem? Quando eu defino isso color="#1976d2" no v-list-group ele já usa essa cor como a dos subitens respectivamente. Verifica por favor o exemplo no Codepen lá irá ver que a classe "filha" usa a mesma cor do elemento pai, o problema é quando altero para um item fora do escopo dos subitens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para corrigir esse problema é necessário colocar no `v-list-group` a propriedade `group`seguida do caminho da URL

Ficando da seguinte forma o exemplo do Codepen:

```
<v-list-group
  :group="'admin'"      
  v-model="item.active"
  :prepend-icon="item.icon"
  no-action
  color="#1976d2"
>
....
</v-list-group>
```